# Atmel Studio 7 - static library undefined function reference

Tags: c, atmel

I have a solution with two projects: 
 - static library 
 - executable

Exec project obviously depends on library. Compiler can figure out where library is and i can use everything(like defined symbols) except contents on IO.c. In output folder i can find coplied IO.o so library is building fine. Error must be on exec project side but I have no clue where to search for it. Google has failed me or i'm searching in wrong direction.

**Static library project has structure like this:**

```
ATMEGA2560
|-headers
| |-IO.h
|-source
| |-IO.c
|-ATMEGA2560.h
```

**Executable project has structure like this:**

```
|-main.c
```

**Compiler Include paths:**

```
../../ATMEGA2560/Release/headers <- IO.h
../../ATMEGA2560/Release/ <- ATMEGA2560.h
```

**All Compiler options**

```
-x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DNDEBUG  -I"E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include" -I"../../ATMEGA2560/Release/headers" -I"../../ATMEGA2560/Release"  -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -mmcu=atmega2560 -B "E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega2560" -c -std=gnu99 -v -MD -MP -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.o)"
```

**Linker libraries:**

```
libm
libATMEGA2560
```

**Linker Libraries paths:**

```
../../ATMEGA2560/Release <- libATMEGA2560.a
```

**All linker options:**

```
-Wl,-static -Wl,-Map="$(OutputFileName).map" -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-lm -Wl,-lATMEGA2560  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-L"../../ATMEGA2560/Release"  -Wl,--gc-sections -mrelax -mmcu=atmega2560 -B "E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega2560" -u _fstat -u _read -u _write
```

**ATMEGA2560.h**

```
#ifndef ATMEGA2560_H_
#define ATMEGA2560_H_

#define F_CPU 16000000L

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#include "headers/IO.h"

#endif
```

**IO.h**

```
#ifndef IO_H_
#define IO_H_

void function_1(void);

#endif
```

**IO.c**

```
#include "../headers/IO.h"

void function_1(void){
    return;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "ATMEGA2560.h"

int main(void)
{
    function_1();
    DDRB = 0b10000000; // configure pin 7 of PORTB as output (digital pin 13 on the Arduino Mega2560)

    while(1)
    {
        PORTB = 0b10000000; // set 7th bit to HIGH
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTB = 0b00000000; // set 7th bit to LOW
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Compilation output:

```
------ Build started: Project: ATMEGA2560, Configuration: Release AVR ------
        Shell Utils Path E:\ATMEL\7.0\shellUtils
        E:\ATMEL\7.0\shellUtils\make.exe all 
        Using built-in specs.
        Reading specs from E:/ATMEL/7.0/Packs/atmel/ATmega_DFP/1.3.300/gcc/dev/atmega2560/device-specs/specs-atmega2560
        COLLECT_GCC=E:\ATMEL\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe
        Target: avr
        Configured with: /home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/src/gcc/configure LDFLAGS=-L/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86-hostlibs/lib CPPFLAGS= --target=avr --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86 --libdir=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86/lib --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-dwarf2 --enable-doc --disable-shared --disable-libada --disable-libssp --disable-nls --with-avrlibc=yes --with-mpfr=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86-hostlibs --with-gmp=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86-hostlibs --with-mpc=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86-hostlibs --enable-win32-registry=avrtoolchain --with-pkgversion=AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778 --with-bugurl=http://www.microchip.com
        Thread model: single
        gcc version 5.4.0 (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778) 
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-funsigned-char' '-funsigned-bitfields' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-I' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include' '-O3' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fpack-struct' '-fshort-enums' '-mrelax' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wundef'  '-B' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega2560' '-c' '-std=gnu99' '-v' '-MD' '-MP' '-MF' 'source/IO.d' '-MT' 'source/IO.d' '-MT' 'source/IO.o' '-o' 'source/IO.o' '-specs=device-specs/specs-atmega2560' '-mmcu=avr6'
         e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/5.4.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -I E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include -imultilib avr6 -iprefix e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/ -MD source/IO.d -MF source/IO.d -MP -MT source/IO.d -MT source/IO.o -D__AVR_ATmega2560__ -D__AVR_DEVICE_NAME__=atmega2560 -D__AVR_DEV_LIB_NAME__=m2560 -D NDEBUG ../source/IO.c -mn-flash=4 -mno-skip-bug -quiet -dumpbase IO.c -mrelax -mmcu=avr6 -auxbase-strip source/IO.o -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -std=gnu99 -version -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -o C:\Users\gothi\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9EwEFa.s
        GNU C99 (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778) version 5.4.0 (avr)
            compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.0.0, MPC version 0.9
        GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
        ignoring nonexistent directory "e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/sys-include"
        ignoring duplicate directory "e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include"
        ignoring duplicate directory "e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include-fixed"
        ignoring nonexistent directory "e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/sys-include"
        ignoring duplicate directory "e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/include"
        #include "..." search starts here:
        #include <...> search starts here:
         E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include
         e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include
         e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include-fixed
         e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/include
        End of search list.
        GNU C99 (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778) version 5.4.0 (avr)
            compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.0.0, MPC version 0.9
        GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
        Compiler executable checksum: 7a32dfd92aeb38c911f2be52b5ef5d52
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-funsigned-char' '-funsigned-bitfields' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-I' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include' '-O3' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fpack-struct' '-fshort-enums' '-mrelax' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wundef'  '-B' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega2560' '-c' '-std=gnu99' '-v' '-MD' '-MP' '-MF' 'source/IO.d' '-MT' 'source/IO.d' '-MT' 'source/IO.o' '-o' 'source/IO.o' '-specs=device-specs/specs-atmega2560' '-mmcu=avr6'
         e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/bin/as.exe -mmcu=avr6 --mlink-relax -mno-skip-bug -o source/IO.o C:\Users\gothi\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9EwEFa.s
        COMPILER_PATH=E:/ATMEL/7.0/Packs/atmel/ATmega_DFP/1.3.300/gcc/dev/atmega2560/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/5.4.0/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/bin/
        LIBRARY_PATH=E:/ATMEL/7.0/Packs/atmel/ATmega_DFP/1.3.300/gcc/dev/atmega2560/avr6/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/avr6/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr6/;E:/ATMEL/7.0/Packs/atmel/ATmega_DFP/1.3.300/gcc/dev/atmega2560/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/lib/
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-funsigned-char' '-funsigned-bitfields' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-I' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include' '-O3' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fpack-struct' '-fshort-enums' '-mrelax' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wundef'  '-B' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega2560' '-c' '-std=gnu99' '-v' '-MD' '-MP' '-MF' 'source/IO.d' '-MT' 'source/IO.d' '-MT' 'source/IO.o' '-o' 'source/IO.o' '-specs=device-specs/specs-atmega2560' '-mmcu=avr6'
        E:\ATMEL\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-ar.exe: creating libATMEGA2560.a
        C:\Windows\System32\xcopy /Y "C:\Users\gothi\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Drone\ATMEGA2560\headers\*.h" "C:\Users\gothi\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Drone\ATMEGA2560\Release\headers\*.h" 
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy /Y "C:\Users\gothi\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Drone\ATMEGA2560\*.h" "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Drone\ATMEGA2560\Release\*.h" 
        C:\Users\gothi\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Drone\ATMEGA2560\headers\IO.h
        1 File(s) copied
        C:\Users\gothi\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Drone\ATMEGA2560\ATMEGA2560.h
        1 File(s) copied
------ Build started: Project: Drone, Configuration: Release AVR ------
        Shell Utils Path E:\ATMEL\7.0\shellUtils
        E:\ATMEL\7.0\shellUtils\make.exe all 
        Using built-in specs.
        Reading specs from E:/ATMEL/7.0/Packs/atmel/ATmega_DFP/1.3.300/gcc/dev/atmega2560/device-specs/specs-atmega2560
        COLLECT_GCC=E:\ATMEL\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe
        Target: avr
        Configured with: /home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/src/gcc/configure LDFLAGS=-L/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86-hostlibs/lib CPPFLAGS= --target=avr --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86 --libdir=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86/lib --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-dwarf2 --enable-doc --disable-shared --disable-libada --disable-libssp --disable-nls --with-avrlibc=yes --with-mpfr=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86-hostlibs --with-gmp=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86-hostlibs --with-mpc=/home/toolsbuild/workspace/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86-hostlibs --enable-win32-registry=avrtoolchain --with-pkgversion=AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778 --with-bugurl=http://www.microchip.com
        Thread model: single
        gcc version 5.4.0 (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778) 
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-funsigned-char' '-funsigned-bitfields' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-I' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include' '-I' '../../ATMEGA2560/Release/headers' '-I' '../../ATMEGA2560/Release' '-O3' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fpack-struct' '-fshort-enums' '-mrelax' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wundef'  '-B' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega2560' '-c' '-std=gnu99' '-v' '-MD' '-MP' '-MF' 'main.d' '-MT' 'main.d' '-MT' 'main.o' '-o' 'main.o' '-specs=device-specs/specs-atmega2560' '-mmcu=avr6'
         e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/5.4.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -I E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include -I ../../ATMEGA2560/Release/headers -I ../../ATMEGA2560/Release -imultilib avr6 -iprefix e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/ -MD main.d -MF main.d -MP -MT main.d -MT main.o -D__AVR_ATmega2560__ -D__AVR_DEVICE_NAME__=atmega2560 -D__AVR_DEV_LIB_NAME__=m2560 -D NDEBUG .././main.c -mn-flash=4 -mno-skip-bug -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mrelax -mmcu=avr6 -auxbase-strip main.o -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -std=gnu99 -version -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -o C:\Users\gothi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvaSiXr.s
        GNU C99 (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778) version 5.4.0 (avr)
            compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.0.0, MPC version 0.9
        GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
        ignoring nonexistent directory "e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/sys-include"
        ignoring duplicate directory "e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include"
        ignoring duplicate directory "e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include-fixed"
        ignoring nonexistent directory "e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/sys-include"
        ignoring duplicate directory "e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/include"
        #include "..." search starts here:
        #include <...> search starts here:
         E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include
         ../../ATMEGA2560/Release/headers
         ../../ATMEGA2560/Release
         e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include
         e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include-fixed
         e:\atmel\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/include
        End of search list.
        GNU C99 (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778) version 5.4.0 (avr)
            compiled by GNU C version 4.7.4, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.0.0, MPC version 0.9
        GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
        Compiler executable checksum: 7a32dfd92aeb38c911f2be52b5ef5d52
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-funsigned-char' '-funsigned-bitfields' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-I' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include' '-I' '../../ATMEGA2560/Release/headers' '-I' '../../ATMEGA2560/Release' '-O3' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fpack-struct' '-fshort-enums' '-mrelax' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wundef'  '-B' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega2560' '-c' '-std=gnu99' '-v' '-MD' '-MP' '-MF' 'main.d' '-MT' 'main.d' '-MT' 'main.o' '-o' 'main.o' '-specs=device-specs/specs-atmega2560' '-mmcu=avr6'
         e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/bin/as.exe -mmcu=avr6 --mlink-relax -mno-skip-bug -o main.o C:\Users\gothi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvaSiXr.s
        COMPILER_PATH=E:/ATMEL/7.0/Packs/atmel/ATmega_DFP/1.3.300/gcc/dev/atmega2560/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/5.4.0/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/bin/
        LIBRARY_PATH=E:/ATMEL/7.0/Packs/atmel/ATmega_DFP/1.3.300/gcc/dev/atmega2560/avr6/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/avr6/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr6/;E:/ATMEL/7.0/Packs/atmel/ATmega_DFP/1.3.300/gcc/dev/atmega2560/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/;e:/atmel/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/lib/
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-funsigned-char' '-funsigned-bitfields' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-I' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include' '-I' '../../ATMEGA2560/Release/headers' '-I' '../../ATMEGA2560/Release' '-O3' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-fpack-struct' '-fshort-enums' '-mrelax' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wundef'  '-B' 'E:\ATMEL\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega2560' '-c' '-std=gnu99' '-v' '-MD' '-MP' '-MF' 'main.d' '-MT' 'main.d' '-MT' 'main.o' '-o' 'main.o' '-specs=device-specs/specs-atmega2560' '-mmcu=avr6'
        main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Drone\Drone\Release\main.c(1,1): error: undefined reference to `function_1'
collect2.exe(0,0): error: ld returned 1 exit status
        make: *** [Drone.elf] Error 1
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Drone\Drone\Release\Makefile(106,1): error: recipe for target 'Drone.elf' failed
Done building project "Drone.cproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I can't tell whether your linker line includes `IO.o` or not — it's hard to know through the blizzard of information.  But your linker error messages suggests that you did not include `IO.o` (or perhaps `IO.c`) on the command line, so the function in the file was not available.

Comment: Thanks for giving us all the information, but the most important parts are missing: There are no command lines of the calls of the compiler and linker. -- And it's strange that an error message of the **linker** appears right after the verbose output of **compiling** `main.c`'s.

Comment: Fields" All linker options" and "All compiler options" has all flags passed to linker/compier respectively

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is just a typo but you say your static library has structure:

```
ATMEGA2560
|-headers
| |-IO.h
|-source
| |-IO.c
|-ATMEGA2560.h
```

but your references are to to a directory with a Release folder in it, like,

```
ATMEGA2560
|-Release
| |-headers
| | |-IO.h
| |-source
| | |-IO.c
| |-ATMEGA2560.h
```

Also, there is avr/io.h and from the AVR libc library and your IO.h. I have had problems with Atmel Studio in the past not telling the difference between files like adc.h and ADC.h. Try renaming your ATMEGA2560 header IO.h to something else (if you can) and maybe that will solve your problem.

Comment: This is project source files structure. I link output files from Release folder.
Renaming files didn't do the trick.

Comment: Taking a step back, the libATMEGA2560.a is where you are trying to call the function_1() from then? That is, build from your source (IO.c) and create a library libATMEGA2560.a? If that's the case, then you will have to rebuild the libATMEGA2560.a because you are changing functions in the source but still referencing the old library code.

Comment: I am aware of that and I did rebuild everything after change. It appears that naming has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I hava an idea. Is there a way to check if `libATMEGA2560.a` linked compiled `IO.o`. Because i have a feeling that library contains function definition from header but did not link source after compiling it??

Comment: I think we are on the same wavelength. From your output above it shows that IO.c gets compiled into IO.o. Weirdly though it doesn't show it being linked in with main.o (maybe that's Atmel Studio hiding output or maybe part of the problem). From my understanding though, building a library requires, like libATMEGA2560.a. So is your intent to build or add to the library or just use it? If it's just to use it, separate it from your source code. If it's to build it and then reference it, you will have to add in the additional steps of building a library.

Comment: Here is a link for building a library from AVR-libc: https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/library.html